# retrieving from multiple tables is taking too long time

Tags: php, sql

Hi i am retrieving from multiple tables and displaying the result but it is taking too long time.

Following is my database code :

```
"SELECT count(distinct KGBupdate.gsxNo) as sat FROM KGBupdate 
    RIGHT JOIN ContactCenter ON KGBupdate.ackNo=ContactCenter.ackNo
    LEFT JOIN CustomerFeed ON ContactCenter.callId = CustomerFeed.callId
    WHERE date(ContactCenter.callClose) BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."'
    AND KGBupdate.gsxNo!=''
    AND ContactCenter.callStatus = 'Close'
    AND CustomerFeed.overall IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND ContactCenter.location='".$location[$i]."' "
```

what is the way to speed up using index

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you call a 'long time'? What indices have you set on what fields?

Comment: indexes on table? use parameters in query, date(ContactCenter.callClose) - if index exists, MySQL don't used him

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(distinct KGBupdate.gsxNo) as sat FROM KGBupdate 
    RIGHT JOIN ContactCenter ON KGBupdate.ackNo=ContactCenter.ackNo and ContactCenter.callStatus = 'Close' and ContactCenter.location='".$location[$i]."' "
    LEFT JOIN CustomerFeed ON ContactCenter.callId = CustomerFeed.callId and CustomerFeed.overall IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    WHERE date(ContactCenter.callClose) BETWEEN '".$start."' AND '".$end."'
    AND KGBupdate.gsxNo!=''
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I dont see any view in your code.. I have just re-formatted your sql, since joined tables sometimes perform better than SARGs.